# Angular - Navigation in ErrorHandler only works with zone.run()

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-errorhandler

I implemented a global error handler in angular (version 5.2.0) for all unhandled exceptions.

The global error handler looks like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggingService } from '../services/logging.service';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  private router: Router;

  constructor(injector: Injector, private zone: NgZone, private loggingService: LoggingService) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router = injector.get(Router);
    });
  }

  handleError(error) {
    this.loggingService.logErrorToApi(error);
    this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/error']));
  }
}
```

The routing only works if I have the call `this.zone.run(...)`.
If I remove this call the routing only adds the route `error` to the URL and doesn't display the component. The ngOnInit isn't called either.

If I have to use such a "hack" to get my routing to work to me it seems that I have a misconfiguration somewhere in my application.

Has someone and idea what I need to change to get it running without the zone call?

---

My routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [CookieGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: !environment.production }),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
    ApiHttpClientService,
    AppSettingsService,
    CookieGuard,
    LoggingService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Here is my error component that I call:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with something like `this.injector.get(Router).navigate...` ? You would ofc first need to save the injected reference to the Injector

Comment: @Jota.Toledo If I try it like this I get the same behaviour. The error route is added to the url but the view doesn't change. :(

Comment: Other than the component not being rendered, do you see any errors/logs in console?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo except the error that causes my error handler to get called, there are no errors in the console. I even see the trace from the routing (because of the enabled tracing). In the html the component gets partially injected but ngOnInit isn't called.

Comment: Does the component has any dependencies? Could you try resolving all the dependencies of the ErrorHandler dynamically through the Injector instance? Could you provide a minimal example to play around?

Comment: I added the error component in my question. It doesn't have any dependencies. I will try to create an example with the problem.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala what I don't understand is why should my error handler be outside of the angular zone? Angular is calling the handler itself... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165160/discussion-between-shamshiel-and-jota-toledo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue myself after removing every service and module from my application and adding them back one by one until the routing broke again. The module **BrowserAnimationsModule** causes the problem.

There is also an open issue on GitHub => https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20290

Answer (score 5):

The errors in the error handlers are out of angular zone.

for instance:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
     NgZone.assertInAngularZone(); // This will throw an error
  }
}
```

For this reason, this is normal to have to wrap navigations into an `ngZone.run()` If you don't do so, angular will not detect the changes and you will end up with a buggy navigation and / or irresponsive pages.

Answer (score -1):

Your LoggingService, to avoid creating a cyclic dependency, should also be in your providers array in app.module.ts.

I Have something like this:

```
providers: [
    CrashReportService,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler},
  ],
```

Comment: My LoggingService is also in the provider list. (I updated my question)

Comment: Then your should not have to injector.get(...

Just put it in your contructor like this:
constructor(
      private loggingService: LoggingService,
      ) {

    }

Comment: It works to normally inject the LoggingService but sadly it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -2):

The thing I did to get around this is to call `window.open(url);`

I think your router does not work because when an Angular app crashes, nothing seems to work anymore. At least this is my experience with it.

Comment: There would have been an error stack if Angular crashed. And Angular is made for creating **Single Page Applications**, opening another tab isn't really recommended ...

Comment: It does not open another tab with the "_self" option. You do what you want to do. But I find it better to present a new uncrashed page to the user with a message than letting him hang there with a crashed page. If you have a better solution or know what IS recommended in this case, I would be very pleased to hear it :)

Comment: @VincentGagnon do you have the same problem in your error handler?

Comment: I don't have any cyclic dependency problem, but regarding your original question about the component that doesn't show after an error if you don't put it in zone.run(), I just used the solution that I gave here. window.open(url, '_self'); It might also feel like a hack, so I'm not sure it's the way to go...

Comment: @VincentGagnon I only have the "cyclic dependency problem" if I try to inject the router in the errorhandler. Can you inject it without a cyclic dependency problem?

Comment: I do not need to inject it as I load the other page using directly window.open(...). I just tried to inject it to see if it would work and got the cyclic dependency error too.